Using variables returned from `derive` between files in ElysiaJS
We have the following code in our index.ts file:
new Elysia()
    .use(bearer())
    .derive(async ({ bearer }) => {
        // Some logic here
        const accountId = ....
        return {
           accountId
        }
    })
    .onBeforeHandle(({ accountId, set }) => {
        if (!accountId) {
            return sendUnauthorizedResponse(set);
        }
    }).use(usersRoutes);

where usersRoutes is imported from another file, and defined as
const usersRoutes = new Elysia({ prefix: '/users' })
            .get('/', async ({ accountId }) => {
                // Logic here that needs to use the accountId
            })

according to their docs about scopes the type of accountId should be inferred (because this is a direct child) but it isn't.
what I tried: adding {as: 'global'} to the derive didn't help, or any other as I tried.
